# Hide the address bar ("omnibox") in Chrome for Android without scrolling?

Tags: chrome-for-android

I'm dealing with a web app that I can't scroll up and down or zoom (scale) in and out, and there is just a tiny bit of the bottom of the page that doesn't fit on the display. Since scrolling and scaling is unavailable, there is simply no way to access it.

However, if I could just hide the Chrome address bar (I believe it's technically called the "omnibox"), then everything would fit. Unfortunately, the only way that I've been able to figure out to hide it is to scroll down the page--which, again, I can't do.

Is there a way to auto-hide the address bar in Chrome for Mobile, without having to scroll down?

Comment: Don't work around the problem: the only way to fix it for everyone is to complain to the developer of the webapp. Likely they have only tested it in Safari on iPhone.

Comment: As a developer myself, I certainly appreciate this sentiment, and I definitely want it fixed. However, I don't think demanding a "real" fix excludes finding a workaround until they *do* fix it.